# Importing a csv file causes a foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, netbeans

Hi I am trying to import a csv file in Mysql but i am getting an error saying that "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails ".Why is this happening and how should i correct it???

Answer (score 0):

One of the columns on the table you're importing data into has a relationship (a foreign key constraint) with another column on another table.

The file you have contains data on at least one column of one row that is not present on the associated column of that other table, thus violating that constraint.

You must identify the row of data that is failing to import. If the tool you're using does not identify the row, you can insert the rows one at a time to see at what point it fails.

Afterwards, you can either fix that row -- if it needs fixing -- or add the value that is being inserted into whatever related table.

The corrective action depends on whether the data you're trying to import is bad or the foreign table is missing something.

Comment: Hmmm the file that i am trying to import has 1082 lines but the table which has the primary key has only 216 rows.The .csv file has repetitons....I am not sure what i should be doing.

Comment: Let's say on the table you're importing into is called SCORES and it has columns COURSE_ID, EXAM_ID, STUDENT_ID. And let's say you have another tabled called STUDENTS with columns STUDENT_ID and STUDENT_NAME. Let's also say you related the table SCORES with the table STUDENTS, creating a foreign key constraint w/ column STUDENT_ID. In this example, to get the error you're getting, you would be adding a record to the SCORES table for a student who does not exist. The STUDENT_ID column value in your CSV file does not exist in the STUDENTS table. It doesn't have anything to do with the row counts